# How do i save my Python crawler output to a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, scraper

I recently started with coding and learning Python, and I am currently working on a webcrawler. So it is currently just printing out the search results. What i want is that it saves the data into a JSON file.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= "http://www.alternate.nl/html/product/listing.html?navId=11622&tk=7&lk=9419"
r = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "listRow"}) 
for item in g_data: 
try: 
    print item.find_all("span", {"class": "name"})[0].text#1
    print item.find_all("span", {"class": "additional"})[0].text#2
    print item.find_all("span", {"class": "info"})[0].text#3
    print item.find_all("span", {"class": "info"})[1].text#4
    print item.find_all("span", {"class": "info"})[2].text#5
    print item.find_all("span", {"class": "price right right10"})[0].text#6
except: 
    pass
```

This is what i want it returns:

```
{"product1":[{"1":"itemfindallresults1"},{"2":"itemfindallresults2"}]} etc
```

So how can i do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First create `my_data = {"product1":[ ... ]}`, next use `json.dump(my_data, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple JSON usage would be:

```
import json
# open the file "filename" in write ("w") mode
file = open("filename", "w")
# just an example dictionary to be dumped into "filename"
output = {"stuff": [1, 2, 3]}
# dumps "output" encoded in the JSON format into "filename"
json.dump(output, file)
file.close()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simple program to meet your requirements.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url= "http://www.alternate.nl/html/product/listing.html?navId=11622&tk=7&lk=9419"
r = requests.get(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

product = Product()

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "listRow"}) 
for item in g_data: 
try: 
    product.set_<field_name>(item.find_all("span", {"class": "name"})[0].text)
    product.set_<field_name>("span", {"class": "additional"})[0].text
    product.set_<field_name>("span", {"class": "info"})[0].text
    product.set_<field_name>("span", {"class": "info"})[1].text
    product.set_<field_name>("span", {"class": "info"})[2].text
    product.set_<field_name>("span", {"class": "price right right10"})[0].text
except: 
    pass  

import json
file = open("filename", "w")
output = {"product1": product}
json.dump(output, file)
file.close()
```